# How to Keep the FCFS and Duplicate Key in map Java8

Tags: java, java-8

**My Input:**

```
DOGA
33
Jhol
25
Krish
34
Rama
25
Krish
21
```

**Required Output**

```
Krish
DOGA
Jhol
Rama
Krish
```

**My output with present code:**

```
DOGA
Rama
Jhol
Krish
```

**Conditions**:

- If two Keys have same Value then preserve the order in which keys
  were inserted.

My code :

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> mm =
            m1.entrySet().stream().sorted((Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())).collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
            mm.entrySet().stream().forEach(s->System.out.println(s.getKey()));
```

I want to achieve the output with `List` implementation, forget all about `Map`

Comment: without `filter`ing, it's not possible to lose a `key` of a map while collecting it back to a map with same `key`... and two keys which are equal are not possible within a `Map`, so definitely something that you're missing to share as a detail to the question.

Comment: I was primarily talking about the current output that you've shared in the question and the second clause of your conditions.

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong to think of the output strings as *keys* if there is repetition. The names may be keys in the data model that you have, but they cannot be keys in any data structure that allows for repetition. Therefore, you cannot use `Map`, using a `List` makes a whole lot more sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes , can you tell me how I use list to achieve the output?

Comment: I don't know what type `m1` currently has. I also don't know why Krish should become before Jhol and if that's because of a requirement or if that is by chance.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes `m1` would be of type `Map<String, Integer>`(based on the comparator used in sorting) and the reason by Krish is ranked higher is the comparator(reversed) as well.

Comment: @BangBang That's not possible, as a `Map` cannot have duplicate keys. Such a `Map` would not adhere to the contract of `Map` and building upon such code would not be the right thing to do.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes , I am talking about list, how can I achieve the output by `List`, forget the map now.

Comment: I gladly forget the `Map` but I cannot change the *input* parameter; only you can do that. If you would present the input as text then just read every line, skipping all even lines and put the strings in a `List`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes , List Input `DOGA 33` `Jhol 25` `Krish 34` Rama 25` `Krish 21` I want output `DOGA Krish Jhol Rama Krish` List comprises of `List<Payer>` , `Player` is made up of `String name` and `int score`

Comment: OK, almost there, why is Krish before Jhol in your output? You say it is based on rank, but note that Krish scores higher than DOGA.

Comment: See, Krish has rank 34 and JHOL has rank 25 , so Krish needs to be ahead of it.

Comment: Req output is : `Krish
DOGA
Jhol
Rama
Krish`

Comment: Ah, OK. So now your question is clear, however your data model is faulty. Your `Player` class doesn't represent a player, it represents a `Score`! If it would implement `Comparable` then you can simply sort the list... I can generate the answer, but the right thing to do is to fix the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's not fix your code, let's fix the model and make things easy. No fancy-pansy use of streams, sorry.

```
public class Scores {

    // renamed Player to Score, added Comparable
    static class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
        private String name;
        private int score;

        public Score(String name, int score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        // and implemented Comparable#compareTo 
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Score that) {
            return Integer.compare(this.score, that.score);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var scores = new LinkedList<Score>();
        scores.add(new Score("DOGA", 33));
        scores.add(new Score("Jhol", 34));
        scores.add(new Score("Krish", 25));
        scores.add(new Score("Rama", 25));
        scores.add(new Score("Krish", 21));

        // now we can just order the scores by sorting in reverse order
        Collections.sort(scores, Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (Score score : scores) {
            System.out.println(score.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this changes the original array, so you may need to copy it first if you want to keep the unsorted array (which is probably ordered chronologically, you may want to include the time in the score as well).

You could of course also reverse the `compareTo` function itself. That would arguably be a better way as you generally want to display the high score first rather than last. Then you would not even require the `Collections.reverseOrder()` parameter to the `sort` operation.

Comment: Hmm, probably should have named that property `points` rather than `score`. Oh well.